# String splitting in ASP.NET doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I'm trying to split a string from a file and to do some transformations around it. I'm working on ASP.NET framework in C#. I know, there could be better ways of storing this type of information than this `.txt` file, but a conversion is not planned right now.

The `.txt` content looks like this:

```
//comment lines
//have to be ignored

1.0.1 [
    # Foo 01/01/2001
    - Text
    - Text
    - ...

    # Bar 02/02/2002
    - Text

    ...
]

1.0.2 [
    ...
]

...
```

This is what I tried:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadText();
}

protected void LoadText(){
    //get file 'update.txt' from server
    string path = Server.MapPath("update.txt");

    //read file removing all lines that start with '//' or empty lines
    string[] cleanTextArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path).Where(line => !line.StartsWith("//") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)).ToArray();

    //merge 'lines' into a single string
    string text = string.Join("\n", cleanTextArray);

    //split text in versions on ']'
    string[] versions = text.Split(']');

    //for each version
    foreach(string version in versions)
    {
        //split version in lines on '['
        string[] lines = version.Split('[');

        Div.InnerHtml += string.Format("<h3>{0}</h3>", lines[0]);

        string changes = lines[1];

        //split changes on "#"
        string[] changesArray = changes.Split('#');

        foreach(string change in changesArray)
        {
            string[] changeArray = change.Split('-');

            string[] changeTitle = changeArray[0].Split(' ');

            string changeAuthor = changeTitle[0];
            string changeDate = changeTitle[1];

            Div.InnerHtml += string.Format("<p><b>{0}</b> on {1}</p><ul>", changeAuthor, changeDate);

            for(int i = 1; i < changeArray.Length; i++)
            {
                Div.InnerHtml += string.Format("<li><p>{0}</p></li>", changeArray[i]);
            }

            Div.InnerHtml += "</ul>";
        }
    }
}
```

Everytime I run it, the page throws an 'IndexOutOfRangeException'. The neat part is that if I cycle through each array and print the result, everything works fine...

What can I do? Thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: Could you run your project in Debug mode and see which line that causes this error? Then you will be able to know what is the issue.

Comment: I already did and also tried some changes. It keeps stopping when I try to read the [1] content, while the array clearly has it (shows up in debugger)

Comment: Have you been able to acquire the value of changesArray?

Comment: Nope, it stops on ```string changes = lines[1];``` and throws exception, but when I inspect the array length, it is 2

Comment: yes, indeed lines array should have length of 2 and lines[1] is accessible. Wondering why you have this strange error here. Could you do some testing by wroking directly with lines[1]. E.g split lines[1] by splitting on new lines

string[] innerLines = lines[1].Split(
    new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" },
    StringSplitOptions.None
);

Comment: Is this failing on the first iteration or  later on?

Comment: As soon as you run it